# Previously installed jhipster 3.12 found after yarn installed 4.0.6

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg, yo

After installing yarn (0.20.3) for the very first time, yo (1.8.5), generator-jhipster with *yarn global add generator-jhipster@4.0.6* and extend the $PATH as mentioned by the installation guide, the new version of jhipster istn't used. Instead, the jhipster 3.12.1 is found, which was always installed by node/npm.

yo is taken from $HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
jhipster 4.0.6 is installed in $HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster

What should I do, that yo takes the latest jhipster installation?

Comment: Are you running it from an existing project? If so you could be using the generator-jhipster from local node_modules, delete your project node_modules and try again.

Comment: no, it was a new project. I had to install/update jhipster by `npm install -g generator-jhipster`

Comment: Maybe you could have tried `npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster`

Comment: yep ... that was my first impulse ... but without luck

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when switching from npm to yarn.
Somehow "yo" still uses npm.
This solved the problem for me:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
npm uninstall -g yo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were previously using NPM before Yarn, this question/answer would probably be relevant and helpful -- goes through the process of removing all of NPM's managed packages and not just for yo and generator-jhipster:

[Yarn package won't upgrade globally (after migrating from NPM)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052606/2238684)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to refuse using yarn and all problems disappeared :)